# Center buttons on a page

Tags: css, html

text-align:center isn't working to center my buttons. I've also tried "margin:0px auto" but that didn't work either. I'm just trying to stack the buttons vertically in the middle of the page with a small space between them. How do I do it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
text-align:center;
margin:0px auto;
background-image:url("one1.jpg");
background-repeat:repeat-x;
}

.bf_button {  
  display:block; 
  background: url(bf_button_fon_right.gif) no-repeat 100%; 
  float: left; 
  outline: none; 
  padding-right: 32px; 
  text-decoration: none; 
 } 

.bf_button:hover {  
  text-decoration: none; 
} 

.bf_button span{  
  display:block; 
  background: url(bf_button_fon_left.gif) no-repeat;  
  white-space: nowrap; 
  line-height: 74px; 
  padding: 0 0 0 32px; 
  font-family: Arial, Verdana; 
  font-size: 34px; 
  font-weight: normal;  
  color: rgb(0,0,0);  
  text-transform: none;  
 }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="one.jpg"></img>
</body>
<div style="text-align:center;">
<br /> <br /> <br />
<a href="http://" class="bf_button"><span>Time & Attendance (Kronos)</span></a>
<br /> <br /> <br />
<a href="http://"  class="bf_button"><span>401K</span></a>
<br /> <br /> <br />
<a href="http://www.bcbsil.com/"  class="bf_button"><span>Medical: </span></a>
<br /> <br /> <br />
<a href="https://"  class="bf_button"><span>Dental, Vision, Life, AD&D: </span></a>
<br /> <br /> <br />
<a href="https://"  class="bf_button"><span>Flex Programs: </span></a>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are floating your buttons to the left, which means they will naturally move to the left.

1. Remove the `float: left;` from `.bf_button`
2. Add a static width to `.bf_button` (since you defined it as a block).
3. Add `margin: 0 auto;` to `.bf_button`

The final CSS definition should look something like this:

```
.bf_button {  
  display:block; 
  background: url(bf_button_fon_right.gif) no-repeat 100%; 
  outline: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-right: 32px; 
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 150px;
 }
```

You can also remove the `<br /> <br /> <br />` as it's not needed when setting the buttons to `display: block;`.  Block elements (or those with display: block) will automatically drop to a new line and stack.  To add spacing, simply add a bottom or top margin to your buttons.

Another note.  You are closing your `<body>` tag too soon.  Your `</body>` tag should be directly before your `</html>` tag.

Comment: It should probably be inline-block.

Comment: Great! That's what I get for downloading button style sheets off the internet that I don't understand. Thanks!

Comment: His application does not require the element to be inline.  As stated, he wanted a list of vertical buttons.  Inline-block would make the buttons collapse into a single row.  I noticed he's using `<br />` tags, which aren't required when using `display: block;`